# Creating nodes and Realtionships in Neo4j Dynamically

Tags: python-3.x, neo4j, py2neo

I have a Directory structure like below

```
C:\Users\Shiva\Desktop\Internship\shiva.txt
```

I want to Create nodes as each folder and I want a relationship between them.

Example Graph will be like this

```
C <-contains-> Users <-contains-> Shiva <-contains-> desktop <-contains-> 

Internship <-contains-> shiva.txt
```

I am going to pass the path in a dynamic way.

Comment: Can you please share what you have done so far? and what are the issues you are facing?

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/BJJQGCwTE

Comment: I have shared in that  link....I want to create nodes for adjecent list like i mentioned above

Comment: createListForFiles(dirName) - It will return all the paths

Comment: Pathlist - ['maven_project', 'maven-simple-master', 'src', 'pom.xml']  Having createrootGraph(pathlist): Hve created node,...now i want to establish a relation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine a solution could be to use Python's [os.walk()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)

This function can be used as this:

```py
from os import walk

def add_node(root, elem):
    query = 'MATCH (r: Directory {{name: "{0}"}})\
                CREATE (e: Directory {{name: "{1}")\
                CREATE (r)-[l: CONTAINS]->(e)\
                RETURN id(e), id(l)'.format(root, elem)
    # Run the query with your driver instance here

# Add the node for root here

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(your_dynamic_path, topdown = False):
    for dir in dirs:
        add_node(root, dir)
    for file in files:
        add_node(root, file)
```

With `add_node(root, elem)` being a function adding/merging the node elem to your Neo4J graph and adding the relation you want.

Comment: I want create a relationships between them

Comment: It looks like I can't put code in the comments so I'll update the answer.